# Android L reveal Effect is not working

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I tried to implement `createCircularReveal()` in `FloatingButton`. But the animation is too fast. How to increase the duration of the Animation. I tried `setDuration(milli-seconds)`, But its not working.

I follow developer.android.com, [Defining Custom Animations](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#reveal)

Here my code:

```
int cx = (fabBtn.getLeft() + fabBtn.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (fabBtn.getTop() + fabBtn.getBottom()) / 2;

int finalRadius = Math.max(fabBtn.getWidth(), fabBtn.getHeight());
Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(fabBtn, cx, cy, 2, finalRadius);
anim.setDuration(2000);
fabBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
anim.start();
```

Comment: Get a better answer, provide version of SDK, Emulator/Device, and Android Version.

Comment: I'm using Android Lollipop 5.0, SDK 21, check in device

Comment: got anything regarding this?

Answer (score 11):

I am also facing the issue as I mentioned and I am able to resolve this issue by getting cx and cy the center position for image view (In your case I think it is button).
**So get cx and cy using this:**

```
int cx = (fabBtn.getWidth()) / 2;
int cy = (fabBtn.getHeight()) / 2;
```

**Instead of this::**

```
int cx = (fabBtn.getLeft() + fabBtn.getRight()) / 2;
int cy = (fabBtn.getTop() + fabBtn.getBottom()) / 2;
```

Comment: Actually, this did work for my, but I do not understand why...I got the original code from the developers page...

Comment: @Boy I found that In original code it failed to call effect from the center of the image that is why I change it to call it from center point and it worked.

Comment: I understand, but that still does not eplain _why_ it doesn't work

Comment: is there any conclusion to the discussion? Which one is the right method?

Comment: @KDeogharkar can you please post full working effect code so that others can also come to know about. Because i have updated the code as you have mention but i am not getting effect like reveal.

Comment: @KDeogharkar, can you please help me.

Comment: @iDroidExplorer I have used same code that is mentioned in https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#reveal just change the way they getting center x and y for button as you can see in my snippet.

Comment: @KDeogharkar Thanks for reply. I have updated same thing. But still not getting effect. Please refer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071154/why-reveal-effect-not-working-as-per-developer-blog

Comment: @KDeogharkar its strange behaviour. When i have checked it in the Emulator of API 21 then its not showing effect but when i have run same thing on real device it shows effect. Is there anything in emulator that prevent having animation?

Comment: i checked in api 21 level emulator only but yes using giniemotion

Answer (score 2):

You might be calling `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` too soon.

So you'll have to use a `getViewTreeObserver()`

Be sure to add a duration to `anim.setDuration(time)` and set the initial visibility of the view to `INVISIBLE`

Here the code:

```
public void checker() {
    myView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(
            new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
                public boolean onPreDraw() {
                    int finalHeight = myView.getMeasuredHeight();
                    int finalWidth = myView.getMeasuredWidth();
                    // Do your work here
                    myView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);

                    cx = finalHeight / 2;
                    cy = finalWidth / 2;


                    finalRadius = Math.max(finalHeight, finalWidth);
                    anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
                    myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    anim.setDuration(3000);
                    anim.start();


                    return true;
                }
            });

}
```

Comment: 3000 duration is real effective change there.
Even 2500 doesn't work in my phone.

Answer (score -1):

I thought I had the same problem, but it seems that, for some reason, a duration of just 2000 milliseconds is not enough for the animation to show. When I set the duration to 3000, I saw a beautiful circle animation.

A small delay of 1 second also helped

```
                // get the center for the clipping circle
                int cx = myView.getWidth() / 2;
                int cy = myView.getHeight() / 2;

                // get the final radius for the clipping circle
                int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

                // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
                Animator anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);
                anim.setStartDelay(1000);

                // make the view visible when the animation starts
                anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation)
                    {
                        super.onAnimationStart(animation);
                        myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                // start the animation
                anim.start();
```

Comment: i am not getting reveal effect. What will be the issue? I have done exact same as you have code here.

Comment: Try increasing the duration even further. It may be because an AVD has quite a low performance.

Comment: Or a add a higher start delay. On a real device the animation might be working properly.