# Why Reveal effect not working as per Developer blog

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, viewanimator, circularreveal

I want to have Reveal Effect with in my app. I come to know about it for how it can be implemented. I got the information from the [Andoid Developer Blog](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal).

But when i have updated that with in my code, it is not showing any effect.

I have also try with [Demo given by Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RevealEffectBasic) to demostrate Reveal effect. But it also not showing the effect. If there any permission i need to add or whats wrong i am doing?

My animator is as below:

```
View button = rootView.findViewById(R.id.button);
    final View shape = rootView.findViewById(R.id.circle);
    shape.setClipToOutline(false);
    shape.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    // Set a listener to reveal the view when clicked.
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            if(isShowing==false){
                // previously invisible view

                // get the center for the clipping circle
                int cx = (shape.getLeft() + shape.getRight()) / 2;
                int cy = (shape.getTop() + shape.getBottom()) / 2;

                // get the final radius for the clipping circle
                int finalRadius = Math.max(shape.getWidth(), shape.getHeight());

                // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
                Animator anim =
                        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(shape, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

                // make the view visible and start the animation
                shape.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                anim.setDuration(4000);
                anim.start();
            }else{

                // get the center for the clipping circle
                int cx = (shape.getLeft() + shape.getRight()) / 2;
                int cy = (shape.getTop() + shape.getBottom()) / 2;

                // get the initial radius for the clipping circle
                int initialRadius = shape.getWidth();

                // create the animation (the final radius is zero)
                Animator anim =
                        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(shape, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);

                // make the view invisible when the animation is done
                anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                        super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
                        shape.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });

                anim.setDuration(4000);
                // start the animation
                anim.start();
            }

            isShowing = !isShowing;

    }
    });
```

Please let me know how to achieve this effect.

Comment: on what version of android are you testing it?

Comment: API version number 20.

Comment: are you testing it on kitkat?

Comment: Ohh god... Yes its Kitkat. But isnt is running that effect in lower than Lollipop?

Comment: most of them have not been backported due of ART. Elevation and Ripple for instance. Probably reveal is one of those

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks for your reply and support. I have weast whole day for that. Because i have observe that some of the other application have made custom view to have such effect. But that is not one given by Lollipop. Anyway Thanks once again.

Comment: I am sorry (that you  wasted a whole day) , you are welcome

Comment: @Blackbelt can you please answer so that i can accept it. As you show me right direction to my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not everything that was introduced with Lollipop was backported. Reveal, ripple and elevation are some examples. The main reason is that some of them rely heavily on the new `UI Thread` introduced whit `ART`. You can find more info [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html), on the very bottom, in the faq section