# Android: Ripple Background Programmatically

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface

I am currently creating an Android app where someone can input their name, press a button, and then it just outputs their name back to them.

One effect that I would like to achieve with this is an effect where, after they push the button, the input and button will vanish (complete this bit so far), and then the background colour of the MainActivity's view will do a ripple (from the centre) with a new colour, eventually changing the full background colour.

How would I go about doing this programatically, since I am only able to find tutorials on adding ripples to buttons when pushed?

Comment: Setting bounty in 3 hours.

Comment: Can you please show what have you tried ?

Comment: Nothing. I don't know where to start. I'm a beginner at Android-y things.

Comment: So I guess first you need to try with button to understand the concept of ripple effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I tested this by making a small app

First of all hide the view you want to reveal in this animation.

The view can be from the same layout and in xml its visibility should be **invisible** so that the animation will **reveal** it.

You can set the view height and width to **match parent** if you want to create a **full screen animation**...

Take your original and reveal view both in **frame layout**

In my case,I have used this:

```
 <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView android:text="Hello World!"                    
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:id="@+id/revealiew"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            >
</FrameLayout>
```

then in your activity on `button click` or some event do this:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // previously invisible view
                View myView = findViewById(R.id.revealview);

// get the center for the clipping circle
                int cx = myView.getWidth() / 2;
                int cy = myView.getHeight() / 2;

// get the final radius for the clipping circle
                int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

// create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
                Animator anim =
                        ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

                //Interpolator for giving effect to animation
                anim.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
                // Duration of the animation
                anim.setDuration(1000);

// make the view visible and start the animation
                myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                anim.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

[image: Attached GIF for your reference]

You can take detailed look at official documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Comment: Have you tested this? Could you include the animated gif I requested within the bounty?

Comment: Sadly, it's not letting me pick your answer as the bounty winner anymore. Or even letting me give you + 25 rep.

Comment: I'll contact staff and ask for help.

Comment: @VishavjeetSingh  how can i start circle reveal  effect in center on button.

Comment: Just replace cx,cy with your button's pivot x,y co-ordinates :
      cx = myButton.getPivotX(); 
      cy = myButton.getPivotY();

Answer (score 7):

What you are describing is a [**reveal effect**](http://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Reveal) on the background.

From the official doc you can find ready to use examples:

1) Here is how to reveal a previously invisible view using reveal effect:

```
 // previously invisible view
 View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

 // get the center for the clipping circle
 int cx = myView.getWidth() / 2;
 int cy = myView.getHeight() / 2;

 // get the final radius for the clipping circle
 int finalRadius = Math.max(myView.getWidth(), myView.getHeight());

 // create the animator for this view (the start radius is zero)
 Animator anim =
     ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, 0, finalRadius);

 // make the view visible and start the animation
 myView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 anim.start();
```

2) Here is how to hide a previously visible view using the reveal effect:

```
 // previously visible view
 final View myView = findViewById(R.id.my_view);

 // get the center for the clipping circle
 int cx = myView.getWidth() / 2;
 int cy = myView.getHeight() / 2;

 // get the initial radius for the clipping circle
 int initialRadius = myView.getWidth();

 // create the animation (the final radius is zero)
 Animator anim =
     ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(myView, cx, cy, initialRadius, 0);

 // make the view invisible when the animation is done
 anim.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
     @Override
     public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
         super.onAnimationEnd(animation);
         myView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     }
 });

 // start the animation
 anim.start();
```

In you app, you can use a colored background layer (invisible at the beginning) and then use the reveal effect on it.

Comment: Excellent answer. I will give it a try tonight (when I can get access to AS) and mark it as the answer if it works.

Comment: I am actively trying this, bounty will be awarded within the next 10-15 minutes.

Comment: Seems to not be animating, but rather just making it appear. How do you have your XML in an example like this?

Comment: @SysVoid You are probably doing something wrong. Start trying this on an empty activity with two nested FrameLayout and make the inner one show/hide using the reveal effect. Take a look here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-RevealEffectBasic

Comment: @SysVoid Take a look alse here for possibile problem with your implementation (es animation duration, getWidth called too early etc..) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27518327/android-l-reveal-effect-is-not-working

Comment: I am getting the width when a button is clicked.

Answer (score -1):

check this site, "Android Ripple Background" is a library to do it and the min sdk is 11 (Android 3.0 Honeycomb)
 https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1107

Comment: Down voted. You never attempted to follow the bounty's rules.