# ImageView Click Ripple Effect

Tags: java, android, xml, rippledrawable

I want to have the kind of effect which we get when we click an icon in an ActionBar . I want to get the same effect when we click an ImageView
An effect like this 
[image: Effect that i want when an imageview is clicked]
This is what i have implemented My Layout

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/add"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

And my back drawable file is like this

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:color="?android:attr/colorControlHighlight">
```

Comment: visit this https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html

Comment: This should lead you in the right direction
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358183/android-ripple-background-programatically